# Convert historical german local time record to UTC in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to convert German local time records, without zone info, i.e.,

```
var data = [
  "2017-12-02 20:27:02",
  "2017-12-02 20:50:00"
]
```

to UTC records, i.e., subtract the time zone offset and respect the daylight saving. I know that there are the `getTimezoneOffset` and `toISOString` functions, which would work if my system locale is set German. For instance I could convert the dates using

```
var d = new Date(data[0])
> Sat Dec 02 2017 20:27:02 GMT+0100 (CET)
d.toISOString()
> '2017-12-02T19:27:02.000Z'
```

However I need a safe solution that works on any server with any locale, e.g., in the cloud.

Comment: use moment and specify the locale?

Comment: The time zone offset can be added in the string too. For example `new Date(data[0] + "z+1")` or `new Date(data[0] + " utc+1")`

Comment: @Slai just adding the offset is not safe, you also need to determine and add or subtract daylight saving offset, which is not easy to do as you need to reason about each specific calendar date. Using moment.js is the better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com) to make date calculations in JavaScript. To parse a date in a specific timezone, you also need `moment.js timezone`. You can then parse the date with your format in the `tz()` function. The date is then available as a `moment` object, with which you can use all `moment.js` features (e.g. time/date calculations, formatting, etc.). See the example below:

```js
var dateString = '2017-12-02 20:27:02';
var dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';
var date = moment.tz(dateString, dateFormat, "Europe/Berlin");

console.log(date.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx to yBrodsky's comment I found a solution using [`moment-timezone`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```
moment = require("moment-timezone")
var d = moment.tz(data[0], "Europe/Berlin").toDate()    
d.toISOString()
> '2017-12-02T19:27:02.000Z'
```